# TAS instruction

Tags: memory

TAS instruction and Memory CPU Registers Read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reliably destructive reads (i.e., a subsequent read without re-write will always read a specific value), test-and-set can be implemented as simply a read with the destroyed value state being defined as the "set" state.

With some additional complexity, the value written after a read can be the swap value rather than the original value providing low-cost atomic swap (of which test-and-set is a special case). This will work even if the destructiveness of the read is not reliable (i.e., old state may be preserved without rewriting) and for more than just swap-in-all-destroyed-value. This can have the advantages both of atomicity and of reduced latency and bandwidth (by using only one read-and-write operation).